# MySQL Innodb CLuster reported negative replicationLag

Tags: lag, mysql-innodb-cluster

The cluster.status() reported something like this -- replicationLag:-00:00:00.003348

I don't understand why the lag could be a negative value? The replication slave finished the write operation before master?

Answer (score 0):

The way 'replicationLag' was calculated in Cluster.status() was incorrect. That has been [fixed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql-shell/8.0/en/news-8-0-30.html) in version 8.0.30, please upgrade MySQL Shell to the latest version.

Comment: The version was 8.0.33, and I upgraded to 8.1.0 last week. But I still got negative lag.